# Wamp : Permission denied when the file is not in "Full Control" for "Everyone" (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, wamp, file-permissions

We have many PDFs on our local server, I have to open them with a fopen in order to add a watermark
But I have a big problem with Windows rights (`right click> Properties> Security`):

Indeed, when I put the file in Full Control to "Everyone" I can open the file without any problem

But when I add only my account (with Full Control), it does not work, I have this error:

```
Warning: fopen (\\ srv-nas \ .. \ file.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...
```

I really do not understand why ... Wamp dynamically changes something?

NB: I can not leave Full Control to everyone for security reasons

Comment: Apache is a Windows Service so will run under whatever account that service is configured to run as, that's the account you need to provide permissions for.

Comment: @AlexK. I'm doing my tests locally for the moment, so Wamp is installed on my computer and I allowed access for my session but it does not work (but when I put for "everyone" I'm there access)

Comment: did you set the permissions for folder or the file ?

Comment: @Balu I gave the rights to the folder, subfolder and files

Comment: Apache does not have rights to that folder unless you give it an Alias in the APache config